# Exercises 1.1.5 Algebraic Topology by Allen Hatcher

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, homotopy-theory

I read in Algebraic Topology by Allen Hatcher :

1.1.5 Show that for a space X, the following  conditions are equivalent:

(a) Every map $S^1 \to X $is homotopic to a constant map, with image a point.

(b) Every map $S^1 \to X $ extends to a map $D^2 \to X$.

now can we prove :

Show that for a space X, the following  conditions are equivalent:

(a) Every map $S^n \to X $is homotopic to a constant map, with image a point.

(b) Every map $S^n \to X $ extends to a map $D^{n+1} \to X$.

is it true ?

Comment: Well, have you tried modifying the proof for $S^1$ to work for $S^n$?